# Run `rails c` on GCloud instace with appengine gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-platform, ruby-on-rails-6

I have a Rails 6.0.0.rc1 application (with the appengine gem install) that I deployed to GCP. Is there a way to log into a remote rails console on the instance that runs the application? I tried this:

```
bundle exec rake appengine:exec -- bundle exec rails c
```

which gives the following output:

```
...
---------- EXECUTE COMMAND ----------
bundle exec rails c
Loading production environment (Rails 6.0.0.rc1)
Switch to inspect mode.
...
```

so apparently it executed the command, but closes the connection right after.

Is there an easy way to do this?

As reference: On Heroku this would simply be:

```
heroku run rails c --app my-application
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few steps involved:

https://gist.github.com/kyptin/e5da270a54abafac2fbfcd9b52cafb61

> If you're running a Rails app in Google App Engine's flexible environment, it takes a bit of setup to get to a rails console attached to your deployed environment. I wanted to document the steps for my own reference and also as an aid to others.
>
> Open the Google App Engine -> instances section of the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) console.
>
> Select the "SSH" drop-down for a running instance. (Which instance? Both of my instances are in the same cluster, and both are running Rails, so it didn't matter for me. YMMV.) You have a choice about how to connect via ssh.
>
> Choose "Open in browser window" to open a web-based SSH session, which is convenient but potentially awkward.
>
> Choose "View gcloud command" to view and copy a gcloud command that you can use from a terminal, which lets you use your favorite terminal app but may require the extra steps of installing the gcloud command and authenticating the gcloud command with GCP.
>
> When you're in the SSH session of your choice, run sudo docker ps to see what docker containers are presently running.
>
> Identify the container of your app. Here's what my output looked like (abbreviated for easier reading). My app's container was the first one.
>
> jeff@aef-default-425eaf...hvj:~$ sudo docker ps
>   CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                       COMMAND                  NAMES
>   38e......552   us.gcr.io/my-project/appengine/default...   "/bin/sh -c 'exec bun"   gaeapp
>   8c0......0ab   gcr.io/google_appengine/cloud-sql-proxy     "/cloud_sql_proxy -di"   focused_lalande
>   855......f92   gcr.io/google_appengine/api-proxy           "/proxy"                 api
>   7ce......0ce   gcr.io/google_appengine/nginx-proxy         "/var/lib/nginx/bin/s"   nginx_proxy
>   25f......bb8   gcr.io/google_appengine/fluentd-logger      "/opt/google-fluentd/"   fluentd_logger
>   Note the container name of your app (gaeapp in my case), and run container_exec  bash.
>
> Add ruby and node to your environment: export PATH=$PATH:/rbenv/versions/2.3.4/bin:/rbenv/bin:/nodejs/bin
>
> cd /app to get to your application code.
>
> Add any necessary environment variables that your Rails application expects to your environment. For example: export DATABASE_URL='...'
>
> If you don't know what your app needs, you can view the full environment of the app with cat app.yaml.
>
> bin/rails console production to start a Rails console in the Rails production environment.